# Get data comparing endate with current date

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a query like this:

```
select F_Exhibition_Name, F_dtFrom as startdate, F_dtTo as enddate
from T_Exhibition
```

My output looks like this:

```
Exhibiton  startdate   enddate
A          2015-05-04  2015-05-21
B          2015-06-10  2015-06-20
C          2015-07-10  2015-09-11
```

I want to get exhibition name only 7 days more after enddate compared to current date.

Comment: for example if end date is today..then i want to show that exhibiton upto 10-sep 2015..like that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below query will show events till 7 days in addition to enddate after checking current date using `Getdate()`:

```
select F_Exhibition_Name from T_Exhibition where   Getdate() < = DATEADD(day,7,enddate )
```

For example :

**Case 1:**

```
Event end date  : 7
Current date    : 1
Show event till : 7 + 7 = 14
So it will be displayed on 1 (1<14)
```

**Case 2:**

```
Event end date  : 8
Current date    : 18
Show event till : 8 + 7 = 15
So it will be not be displayed on as 8 > 15
```

Hope that puts light on the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Please use below query

```
 select F_Exhibition_Name,F_dtFrom as startdate,CASE WHEN CONVERT(date,F_dtTo)=CONVERT(DATE,GETDATE()) THEN DATEADD(DAY,7,F_dtTo) else F_dtTo end   as enddate from T_Exhibition
```

Comment: this is wrong sir.for example if end date is today..then i want to show that exhibiton upto 10-sep 2015..like that

Comment: You want to show all the exhibitons  between today and 10-sep 2015 right?

Comment: no sir..i want to show all exhibtion ,but if end date is tody.then i want to show that exhibtion upto 10 sep-2015

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming you want `F_dtTo` to be at least seven days greater than `F_dtFrom`:

```
SELECT F_Exhibition_Name,
       F_dtFrom AS startdate
       F_dtTo AS enddate
FROM T_Exhibition
WHERE DATEDIFF(day, F_dtFrom , F_dtTo) >= 7;
```

[This MSDN link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186724.aspx#GetDateandTimeDifference) has more useful Datetime functions.

Comment: sir i dont want to comapte fdtfrom..i only looking for end date.for example if end date is today..then i want to show that exhibiton upto 10-sep 2015..like that